# what is double timer do in this code?

Tags: android

i use this sample code for delete current notification is work fine but i wants to know what is doing this timer in this code? i want to delete notification every 19 second  so in my code there is two timer which one i change if i want to delete notification every 30 minutes?? what is the function of this tewo timer? `myTimer.schedule(myTask, 19 * 1000 , 19 * 1000);` which one i change if i  make delete notification every 30 minutes???

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {

    NotificationManager nm;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence from = "CherryApplication";
        CharSequence message = "Launcher application for games.";

        MyTimerTask myTask = new MyTimerTask();
        Timer myTimer = new Timer();

        Intent startMyActivity = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                startMyActivity, 0);
        Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.cherry_icon,
                "CherryApplication", System.currentTimeMillis());
        notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
        nm.notify(1, notif);
        myTimer.schedule(myTask, 19 * 1000, 19 * 1000);
    }

    class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        public void run() {
            nm.cancel(1);

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first value is the delay, and the second one is the period. See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29):

To answer your question, you need to change both values

```
// in 30 minutes, followed by every 30 minutes
myTimer.schedule(myTask, 30 * 60 * 1000 , 30 * 60 * 1000);
```

Comment: delay means how long this effeor work?? so if i use this function is as a delete notification at every 15 minustes is this work??
myTimer.schedule(myTask, 2 * 1000 , 30 * 60 * 1000); 

so delete notification at every 30 minutes and duration is 2 second???

Comment: The duration of what? I don't get you

Comment: i mean i sent notification at every 15 minutes using this code

 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        (900 * 1000), pendingIntent);

Comment: now i want to delete notification at every 14minute and 55 seconds so when new notification wil come at 15 minutes popup will appear

Comment: what does happening if i use delay 0??? like this     myTimer.schedule(myTask, 0 , 873 * 1000);

Comment: this is my code which sent notification at every 15 minutes

   intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        (900 * 1000), pendingIntent);
      System.out.println("Calling Alaram...");
     }

Comment: this is my code which delete notification how do i set this to delete notifcation at every 14minutes55 seconds? so notification will show  always and also pop up at every 15 minites

Comment: Correct, if you set delay = 0, the task should execute immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you check `Timer.schedule` API you would see that te second parameter indicates you time in milliseconds from now of your first "task run" and the third one indicates you how often your task will run again.

So, if you want to run your task every 30 min you should type this.

```
myTimer.schedule(myTask,30*60*1000,30*60*1000);
```

Comment: but one time is delay??? i want perform this action every 30 minutes by only for 2 seconds

Comment: because im sending notification at every 30 minutes from other class so this class will remove notification at every 30 minutes  so is like a pop up of new notification which sending by other class 

my other class timer is this 
 am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(),
        (900 * 1000), pendingIntent);

i want to delete this mesage at every 14minutes and55 second so new notifiction always exist in phone and is show popup at every 15 minutes

Comment: You dont need to delete your notification to make the another one to popup in your notification bar. If you launch again the notification (with the same id as the old one) you will get your notification updated and the effect of a new notification will appear aswell.

Comment: no i just one to give notification every 15 minutes either app is running or not

Comment: myTimer.schedule(myTask, 2 * 1000 , 30 * 60 * 1000); MEANS that you will clean your first notification in 2 seconds and the next ones every 30 minutes after those 2 seconds

Comment: i just want to delete notification at every   myTimer.schedule(myTask, 2 * 1000 , 873 * 1000);    

 873 * 1000  mnot just 2 seonds so how do i set this?  can i use 0 for delay??

Comment: no i dont want launch again application every 15 minutes i just wnat to show notification alway son notification bae either user use app or not and show pop up at every 15 minutes so my appnotifictaion always present in notification bar

Comment: so  u mean i write both one is  myTimer.schedule(myTask, 873 * 1000 , 873 * 1000) so first one dleete at 14minutes 55 second and next onee also delete at after 14 minute 55 second??

Comment: If you want your notification stay always in the notification bar no matter what look for [foreground services](http://chris.boyle.name/2012/03/android-foreground-service-notifications)

Comment: Anyway if you want to use your timer I would type `myTimer.schedule(myTask, 895 * 1000 , 900 * 1000)` This way your notification will be erased in 14 min and 55 secs after the timed was started an then every 15 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29). it explains the function better. To summarize:

```
public void schedule (TimerTask task, long delay, long period)
```

Added in API level 1
Schedule a task for repeated fixed-delay execution after a specific delay.

**Parameters**
*task*  the task to schedule.
*delay* amount of time in milliseconds before first execution.
*period*    amount of time in milliseconds between subsequent executions.
**Throws**
*IllegalArgumentException*  if delay < 0 or period <= 0.
*IllegalStateException* if the Timer has been canceled, or if the task has been scheduled or canceled.

Comment: This is the start delay. If you want your task to start immediately, I guess you can put 0 milliseconds and then for the period, you can put 30 * 60 * 1000 - which equals to 30 seconds.